# Python Type Hint a Return Value Dependent on Return Type of Another Method

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-3.10, type-variables

I have a setup that looks like the following:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from pathlib import Path

class Foo:
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def base_path(self) -> Path:
        ...

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def files(self) -> str | list[str] | dict[str, str]:
        ...

    @property
    def paths(self) -> Path | list[Path] | dict[str, Path]:
        if isinstance(self.files, str):
            return self.base_path / self.files
        if isinstance(self.files, list):
            return [self.base_path / file for file in self.files]
        if isinstance(self.files, dict):
            return {key:self.base_path / file for key, file in self.files.items()}

class Bar(Foo)
    base_path = Path("xyz")
    files = "file1"

class Baz(Foo)
    base_path = Path("xyz")
    files = ["file1", "file2"]
```

How do I need to set up the type-hinting inside `Foo`, such that `mypy` to automagically recognize `Bar.paths` as `Path` and `Baz.paths` as `list[Path]` ?

Currently, I am manually type hinting `paths` in every subclass.

Comment: If you can live without property, then [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=8da6b8e4dbe60c1337bc71cb44a6021f) works. Overloaded properties are not supported for some reason.

Comment: @SUTerliakov That's a pretty nifty idea, but it seems more work than what I am currently doing (manually hinting `paths` in every subclass)

Comment: This is not required, annotation from `files` can be safely ignored. Sorry, it was just quick attempt. Required part is annotation in generic (inheriting from `Foo[str]`, not just `Foo`), everything else is inferred.